# Regex to include white space and then verify a character

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a pattern to search around web but im new to it and unable to verify it.

Im looking for example

> [verify if any whitespace]  [any of this char ':' '|' ';']   [verify if any whitespace]   [[String a-zA-Z0-9-]+]

Suppose Test String -

> " : hello129 "  or ":hello129" or ";hello129" or "|hello129" or " | hello129"

My attemps

```
 \s[:;|]\s[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+

(\w+\s\w+):(\w+\s\w+)[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+
```

Please suggest me possible solutions for this pattern in regex/regular expressions

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Pls provide sample input, expected output, and your own attempts.

Comment: my attempt : (\w+\s\w+):(\w+\s\w+)[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+

Comment: You can use the interactive  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to test your regular expression and to see what patterns are matching.

Comment: expected output:  " : string" example " : hello0123"

Comment: Put in the question, not the comments ;)

Comment: `/^\s+([.|;])\s+[a-z0-9_+-]+$/`

Comment: @ArtofDebug Did my question solve your problem? In this case, please mark it as the correct solution in order to help all future StackOverflow users. If you still have questions, please just comment on my answer and I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace is represented with `\s`. The other groups are easily written in brackets. 
Whitespace could by one or more characters, so the `+` modifier will be necessary. If Whitespace was optional, the `*` would have been okay as well. If only one character of whitespace would be allowed, we would leave the modifier out.
The string in the end is one or more characters long and needs the `+` as well.

The result is a regular expression like this:

```
\s+[:;|]\s+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+
```

[Here is an example including tests on the great RegEx testing site regex101.com.](https://regex101.com/r/c3R3yH/1)

Comment: is there any possible way without using `\s` , because this does not gives me result, im just facing problem with whitespace

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing with `\s`? You could split it up and specify more exactly which kinds of whitespace you need (Space, tabs, newlines). Right now, we are only checking for any possible kinds of whitespace.